# Function like jQuery's position but not instant

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So let's say I have to `div`s and I want to animate one so that it ends up on top of the other, slowly moving towards it. I know I can use `animate()`, but I don't know how to specify the coordinates of the destination, which I don't know *a priori*.

With jQuery UI, I can do something like

```
$("#moving_element").position({
        my:        "left top",
        at:        "left top",
        of:        $("#destination_element"),
        collision: "fit"
    })
```

but there's no speed parameter: the change is instantaneous.

To give an example of what I'm after, here's what the GUI I'm working with looks like. One or more cards can be selected and, when a button is clicked, they have to all move towards the red covered card from whatever position they were in.

[image]

How can I achieve what I'm after? Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with animate. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.animateTo = function(obj, ms) {
    if (obj.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (ms == undefined) {
      ms = 400; // Default
    }
    obj = $(obj);
    var p = obj.position();
    $(this).animate({
      top: (p.top + 26) + "px",
      left: p.left + "px"
    }, ms);
  }
  $("#draggable").draggable().dblclick(function(e) {
    $(this).animateTo(".ace", 500);
  });
})
```

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
}

#draggable {
  top: 150px;
  left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="field">
  <div class="card ui-widget-content ace">Ace</div>
  <div id="draggable" class="card ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag Me<br />Double Click Me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will allow you to animate the movement of the card to a specific position.

**.animateTo( Selector or Element or jQuery Object )**

> Description: Animate the position of an element relative to another element.